# Getting 404 while accessing a webpage through jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am getting 404 while accessing a webpage though jsoup. But the page loads fine when accesses through a browser.

I was able to access the page through jsoup few days back. But now it throws 404.
Tried to add User-Agent, timeout etc. but no luck.

In Firebug as well, I am getting 404 for the request, but the page loads fine in the browser.

Not sure how the page gets rendered in the browser but not through Java Program.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/stock.php?"+quote).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36")
             .timeout(1000*7).get();
```

On executing the Java program, getting below error:

> org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://example.com/stock.php?AAA
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Are you sure the browser loads? May be from cache?

Comment: @Areca, I tried clearing the cache as well. Still no luck.

Comment: If you post your full code then we will be able to help you diagnose. Until then, my guess is that your code configures a different set of proxy servers to what your web browser does.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please consider accepting the given answer. If it is not solved, you may want to give the concrete URL so that we can start analyzing.

Comment: The issue is resolved now. There was a problem with the website itself, which is resolved now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

By default `Jsoup` throws an exception when it receives an HTTP error. You can set the `ignoreHttpErrors` to `true` to read the page contents even if the page returned an error.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
                 .connect("http://example.com/stock.php?"+quote)
                 .userAgent("...")
                 .timeout(1000*7)
                 .ignoreHttpErrors(true) 
                 .get();
```